# Remove <tr> added with json request on the second click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a forum page based on an API. When an image is clicked, it loads the body text of the topic.

This is the code i use to add the body text below the topic title:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    tid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php?tid=' + tid,
        success: function(data) {
            $('tr#' + tid).after("<tr><td colspan=\"7\">" + data + "</td></tr>");
        }
    });
});
```

How do I remove this again on the second click? Right now it just adds another div below the TR.

Comment: Have you tried just using .after("").after("<tr><td colspan=\"7\">" + data + "</td></tr>");  This should empty the contents, then insert th next?

Comment: Or - just at the beginning of the click function, empty the field with .html("")?

Comment: @ntgCleaner, no it wouldn't.. that would insert an empty textnode and then a `tr`

Comment: can you use .html("<tr><td colspan=\"7\">" + data + "</td></tr>"); instead of .after?  I think the entire purpose of .after is to ADD on to the end

Comment: @ntgCleaner `.html()` will replace the contents of the current element, but the OP wants to add a new `tr` after the one that has id equal to `tid`, You must be confusing it with `.append()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put an id for the inserted element, and check for its existence

```
$('img').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).parent(), 
        tid = row.attr('id'),
        bodyId = tid+'-body', // new id based on tid
        body = $('#'+bodyId);

    if (body.length){ // if topic body exists
        body.remove(); // remove it
    } else { // otherwise add it
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php?tid=' + tid,
            success: function(data) {
                row.after('<tr id="' + bodyId + '"><td colspan="7">' + data + '</td></tr>');
           }
    });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $thisParentTr = $this.closest('tr'),
        tid = $thisParentTr.attr('id');
    if ($thisParentTr.next().hasClass('topic-added')) {
        $thisParentTr.next().remove();
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php?tid=' + tid,
            success: function(data) {
                $thisParentTr.after("<tr class=\"topic-added\"><td colspan=\"7\">" + data + "</td></tr>");
            }
        });
    }
});​
```

However I would recommend just hiding and showing once it's been called in to save on an additional request in case they click it again.

**Addition** - Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UF5Jt/1/) with my recommendation of checking if new tr is there, if not get new; if yes and visible then hide, if yes and hidden then show. There may be some tidying up you can do but I'd recommend this over letting people make ajax calls over and over by just clicking an image.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would not recommend the use of after when selecting by id as after is an iterator while all you really want is set innerHTML with html()
You could put a condition of some sort around it, the easiest is probably a flag:

```
    $('img').click(function() {
         flag = false;
         oldHTML = "";
         tid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
         $.ajax({
              url: 'ajax.php?tid=' + tid,
              success: function(data) {
                  if !(flag){
                      oldHTML = $('tr#' + tid).html();
                      $('tr#' + tid).html(oldHTML+"<tr><td colspan=\"7\">" + data + "</td></tr>");
                      flag = true;
                  } else {
                      flag = false;
                      $('tr#' + tid).html(oldHTML);
                  }
              }
         });
     });
```

A better way would be to explicitly check the contents of the next tr using something like:

```
     if$('tr#' + tid).html().indexOf(data) != -1{
```

Or alternately prewrite the row, and then use .show() and .hide() to toggle its display.